# PHP - Call function inside function

Tags: php, frameworks

I am making a php framework, and i want to make the prefix set grouped. Like laravel's :

```
$router->group(['middleware'=>'auth', 'prefix'=>'test'], function (){
    return $router->get("/","IndexController@index");
});
```

This is my Router

```
public function group($group = [], $callback){
    // How To call the callback?
}
```

Or I Can't Do It?

Comment: With `$callback()`

Comment: Thank you, but it not work. `Undefined variable $router`

Comment: We should imagine the code where this happens? Or will you make an effort and edit your question?

Comment: Change `$router->get` to `$this->get` and then use `$callback()`